# When is it appropriate to apply a change of variable during integration?

Tags: integration, substitution, change-of-variable

Often I see the technique [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables) applied to the domain of integration where one replaces the [integration symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Meaning_of_the_symbol_dx) with a [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative):

$$
dx = dx\frac{du}{du} = \frac{dx}{du}du = \left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^{-1}du
$$

where $u(x)$ denotes the replacement variable. This apparently relies on the interpretation of $dx$ and $du$ as [infinitesimally "small pieces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Meaning_of_the_symbol_dx) which seems to be disputed.

I know that when it comes to integration the correct way of applying this change of variables is via [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). Let's consider the following example:

$$
\int_a^bx^3dx \stackrel{u(x) \equiv x^2}{=} \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}\sqrt{u}\cdot u \underbrace{\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^{-1}}_{\frac{1}{2x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}}du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a^2}^{b^2}u\,du = \left[\frac{u^2}{4}\right]_{u=a^2}^{u=b^2}
$$

Actually this is obtained via integration by substitution:

$$
\int_a^bx^3dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b2x\cdot x^2dx\stackrel{u(x) \equiv x^2}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}u\,du = \left[\frac{u^2}{4}\right]_{u=a^2}^{u=b^2}
$$

Now for this example the latter decomposition into substitute $u(x)$ and its derivative $u'(x)$ is obvious but often, I find, this is not the case. Consider for example:

$$
\int_a^b J_0\left(\exp(\sigma\cdot x)\right)dx
$$

where $J_0$ denotes the Bessel function of first kind and order. Finding such a decomposition here is non-obvious but on the other hand it's tempting to apply a change of variables $u(x) \equiv \exp(\sigma\cdot x)$ which leads to:

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{\exp(\sigma a)}^{\exp(\sigma b)} \frac{J_0(u)}{u}du
$$

which can be solved using [Meijer G-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function). Now in reverse order it's possible to deduce the decomposition from the integrand but carrying out the integration by substitution is way more complicated.

So this eventually brings me to my question. Since often it is easier (more obvious and more convenient) to apply a change of variables than to perform integration by substitution, are there any limitations to this method (in terms of applicability) I should be aware of? Can I *always* perform a change of variables or do I need to crosscheck its validity by deducing the corresponding substitution rule? Or are the two methods actually (inherently) the same?

Comment: I don't think I've ever the sequences of equations $dx = dx\frac{du}{du} = \frac{dx}{du}du$ until I read your question. I wonder where this came from. It doesn't seem to be in any of the links you offered.

Comment: @DavidK That sequence is a long form of the equation $dx = \left(\frac{d}{du}x\right)du$ where $dx$ and $du$ are treated as stand-alone pieces. This was also mentioned in one of the [Wikipedia articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Integral&oldid=848691053#Meaning_of_the_symbol_dx) (the version from 2018). This however seems to be debatable, since some sources mention that the symbol $dx$ only makes sense when used together with the integral. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals) also mentions $dx = \dots du$.

Comment: Lots of things get into Wikipedia. You noticed that this particular derivation was there once and now is not; this should be a clue that there was a reason for removing it from the article. If you regard $dx$ as merely part of the integral notation, $dx = \left(\frac{d}{du}x\right)du$ isn't truly meaningful, but it is a good formal procedure ("formal" in the sense that it has the *form* of an equation) to use while rewriting the integral. If you regard $dx$ as a differential then you can prove $dx = \left(\frac{d}{du}x\right)du$ (where $\frac{d}{du}x$ is a derivative) ...

Comment: ... without pretending that $\frac{d}{du}x$ is $dx$ divided by $du.$ Either way, we're not relying on 17th-century notions that the Wikipedia article refers to as the "historical" interpretation of $dx$ and $du.$ Admittedly, the intuition of those notions is so powerful that it usually leads to correct answers and is useful in mnemonics.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking about is sometimes called the inverse substitution theorem. A few months ago I found that someone had actually written a paper taking issue with how integration by substitution is taught, that you may find enlightening: Gale, D. [*Teaching Integration by Substitution*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975317), The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 101, No. 6 (Jun.–Jul., 1994), pp. 520–526 .

Since that's probably still paywalled, I'll summarise the particularly relevant bit (page 4 of the PDF copy):

> **Inverse Substitution Theorem** If $h=(f \circ g) \cdot g'$, $H'=h$ and $g$ has an inverse,
>   $$ (H \circ g^{-1})' = f. $$

The paper offers two proofs of this, one that uses the Inverse Function Theorem but concludes that $f$ has an antiderivative, and one that assumes $f$ has an antiderivative $F$, but does not need the Inverse Function Theorem. The former is surely a more useful set of hypotheses, and that proof goes as follows:

$$ (H \circ g^{-1})' = (H' \circ g^{-1}) \cdot (g^{-1})' = ([(f \circ g) \cdot g'] \circ g^{-1} ) \cdot (g^{-1})', $$
by the chain rule and the definition of $h$. The first bracket expands to
$$ [(f \circ g) \circ g^{-1}] \cdot ( g' \circ g^{-1} ), $$
and then the first bracket here simplifies to $f$ by associativity of function composition, so we have
$$ f \cdot (g' \circ g^{-1}) \cdot (g^{-1})', $$
and the last two terms are the derivative of $g \circ g^{-1}$, i.e. the identity function, which has derivative $1$, and hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

Change of variable and substitution are the same.

The difference is only in names. In general whenever the substitution makes an integral easier to evaluate we change variable.

Comment: Actually my question is not about terminology. I understand that integration by substitution formally involves a "change of variable" but by the latter I referred to the trick of treating $dx$ as an infinitesimal distance and hence converting it into a derivative. For me it is not clear if this trick can be applied under any circumstances and whether or how it is related to the formally correct integration by substitution.

Comment: @a_guest du=u'dx is the key, dx is not a derivative, it is a symbol which stands for the linearized change in the variable $x$